# Trying to implement a generic linked list that gets functions from the user

Tags: c, list, generics

The basic idea of this program is implementing a generic sorted linked list that gets functions from the user (i have a main file which includes these 2 files and does nothing).
edit: the problem was that my declarations were declared before the struct.

my header:

```
#ifndef GADT_H
#define GADT_H
#include <stdio.h>
//typedef declaration
typedef void* ELM;
typedef void* SLN;
typedef void* HEAD;
typedef enum { success, outOfMem, badArgs, failure} RESULT;

HEAD SLCreate(ELM head_val, ELM(*create_elm)(), void(*cpy_elm)(ELM, ELM),
int(*cmp_elm)( ELM, ELM), void(*free_elm)(ELM),
void(*print_elm)( ELM), ELM(*add_elm_to_elm)(ELM, ELM));
void SLDestroy(HEAD head);
RESULT SLAddListElement(HEAD* head, ELM node);
RESULT SLRemoveElement(HEAD* head, ELM node);
SLN SLFindElement(HEAD head, ELM node);
void SLAddToElement(HEAD* head, ELM toEl, ELM addEl);
void SLPrintElements(HEAD head);
#endif
```

my c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "gadt.h"
//static funcs:
static void sortLinkedList(HEAD* head); 
static void nodeDataSwap(Node* nodeOne, Node* nodeTwo);
typedef struct Node{
    ELM data;
    struct Node * next;
    //Functions associated with the struct.
    ELM(*create_elm)();
    void(*cpy_elm)(ELM, ELM);
    int(*cmp_elm)( ELM, ELM);
    void(*free_elm)(ELM);
    void(*print_elm)( ELM);
    ELM(*add_elm_to_elm)(ELM, ELM);
}Node;
/************************************************************************
* function name: SLCreate
* The input: a pointer to a value(void*), pointers to functions
  that are associated with the struct.
* The output: void*
* the operation: creates the a pointer to a new linked list
 and initializes its functions.
*************************************************************************/
extern HEAD SLCreate(ELM head_val, ELM(*create_elm)(), void(*cpy_elm)(ELM, ELM),
int(*cmp_elm)( ELM, ELM), void(*free_elm)(ELM),
void(*print_elm)( ELM), ELM(*add_elm_to_elm)(ELM, ELM)){
    HEAD head;
    Node* pToFirstNode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pToFirstNode!=NULL){ //if the allocation hasn't failed
        pToFirstNode->data=(ELM)create_elm();
        cpy_elm(pToFirstNode->data, head_val);
        pToFirstNode->next=NULL;
        //initializing functions assosiated with Head.
        pToFirstNode->cpy_elm=cpy_elm;
        pToFirstNode->create_elm=create_elm;
        pToFirstNode->cmp_elm=cmp_elm;
        pToFirstNode->free_elm=free_elm;
        pToFirstNode->print_elm=print_elm;
        pToFirstNode->add_elm_to_elm=add_elm_to_elm;
        head=pToFirstNode; //so both of them point ot the same place
        return head;
    }
    return;
}
/************************************************************************
* function name: SLAddListElement
* The input: the head of the list and the node to be created
* The output: integer-RESULT (outOfMem, Succes)
* the operation:goes to the end of the linked list, allocates memory at the end
and copies node to it.
*************************************************************************/
extern RESULT SLAddListElement(HEAD* head, ELM node){
    Node* currNode=(Node*)(*head);
    Node* lastNode=(Node*)(*head);
    while(currNode->next!=NULL){
        lastNode=currNode;
        currNode=currNode->next;
    }
    currNode=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(currNode==NULL){
        return outOfMem;
    }
    //inserting functions into currNode
    currNode->add_elm_to_elm=lastNode->add_elm_to_elm;
    currNode->cpy_elm=lastNode->cpy_elm;
    currNode->create_elm=lastNode->create_elm;
    currNode->free_elm=lastNode->free_elm;
    currNode->print_elm=lastNode->print_elm;
    currNode->cmp_elm=lastNode->cmp_elm;
    //inserting data into currNode
    currNode->cpy_elm(currNode->data,node);//calls the function from head.
    currNode->next=NULL;
    //sort the list
    sortLinkedList(head);

    return success;
}

extern void SLDestroy(HEAD head){
    Node* currNode=(Node*)head;
    Node* subsequentNode=(Node*)head; //next node after previous
    //need two pointers because after i free the first one 
    //i dont have access to the next node.
    while(currNode->next!=NULL){
        subsequentNode=subsequentNode->next;
        currNode->free_elm(currNode->data);
        free(currNode);
        currNode=subsequentNode;
    }
}
static void sortLinkedList(HEAD* head){
    Node* currNode=(Node*)(*head);
    while(currNode->next=NULL);
    if(currNode->cmp_elm(currNode->data,currNode->next->data) > 0){
        nodeDataSwap(currNode,currNode->next);
    }
}
static void nodeDataSwap(Node* nodeOne, Node* nodeTwo){
    void * temp;
    temp=nodeOne->data;
    nodeOne->data=nodeTwo->data;
    nodeTwo->data=temp;
}

extern void SLPrintElements(HEAD head){
    Node* nodePointer=(Node*)head;
    nodePointer->print_elm(nodePointer->data);
    while (nodePointer=NULL){
        printf("\n\t");
        nodePointer->print_elm(nodePointer->data);
    }
}
```

these are the errors i get:[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCW8l.png)

i have a feeling the problems are connected to the definition of my struct but i'm not sure, would love some help

Comment: "i get tons of syntax errors" -->  These are useful to you in determining what is wrong.    Including the text of those errors is helpful for SO too.  Suggest adding them here.

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` pointers. And don't use `void *` excessively. Your code is extremely error-prone and hard to read. Use self-documenting names, upper-case names only for macros and `enum`-constants and spaces around binary operators. And see [ask] We are no tutoring or debugging service.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should _not_ cast the return value from `malloc()`. And it would increase readability if you used typedefs for your function pointer arguments.

Comment: @Gerhardh: "... if you used typedefs for your function pointer arguments" - which would counter both of us strongly discouraging `typedef`ing pointers. Yes, no rule without exeption. After all rules are not religious commandments :-)

Comment: @Olaf, yes you are right. But as functions are always pointers there is not so much information hidden than with normal data types. And it looks **much** cleaner. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh: Functions are **not** pointers! As much as arrays are not pointers! Both decay to a pointer for most usages, though. Try `sizeof(int(int))` and `sizeof(int (*)(int))`. Pointers are first-class types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your type definitions.
**Never ever** hide pointer in typedef'd types!

```
typedef void* HEAD;  // DANGER!! DANGER!! DANGER!!

...

extern RESULT SLAddListElement(HEAD* head, ELM node){
    Node* currNode=(Node*)head;  // <= BOOM
```

`HEAD*` means `void **` in tht end.
You convert `head` which his pointer to pointer to something into `Node*` which is pointer to struct. This is very likely a mismatch in level of indirection.

Even if you don't get tiny red thingys in your text editor, the error messages from Visual Studio should contain some text and some line information.
You should always include the error messages in your questions to allow better analysis.

Edit:
Missing header might also be a problem:

```
#include "Gadf.h"  <== Probably you want gadt.h
```